# Is it more correct to use <main> or <article> for the main content of a page which is also an article?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm currently cleaning up my personal blog and I'm trying to make the HTML adhere correctly to HTML standards. The blog structure is simple. I have a home page that links to blog posts and a page for each blog post.

For the blog post pages. I'm not sure if I should use the `<main>` or `<article>` tag to wrap all of the content.

I would either use

```html
<html>
<body>
  { heading, navigation, etc. }
  <main>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <time datetime="{publish date}">{human readable publish date}</time>

    {content}
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

or

```html
<html>
<body>
  { heading, navigation, etc. }
  <article>
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <time datetime="{publish date}">{human readable publish date}</time>

    {content}
  </article>
</body>
</html>
```

If I read the [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sections.html#elementdef-article) for `<article>` correctly,
using `<main>` seems to be the better option because `<article>` is meant to separate independent self-contained parts of an HTML document while `<main>` is meant to indicate where the main part of the document or meat of the document.

The reason I'm hesitating is because `<article>` works with the `<time>` element to allow me to specify when the post was published.

From MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article):

> The publication date and time of an  element can be described using the datetime attribute of a  element. Note that the pubdate attribute of  is no longer a part of the W3C HTML 5 standard.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article   read the definition examples =P

Comment: I don't know what the MDN justification for their statement about the use of the `<time>` element with `<article>`. There's nothing in the W3C HTML5 spec or the WHATWG HTML Living spec to back that up. The `<time>` element *can* be used to provide a publication date, but only in combination with its use either in prose `<p>Publication date: <time> ... </time>` or RDFa `<time property="published" datetime="...">...</time>` or Microdata `<time itemprop="published" datetime="...">...</time>`. All of these are indepedent of the container element.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from using both, either. The spec just as well allows that.

Comment: The difference is this: an `article` is a narrative. A `main` can consist of other matters as well: a photo gallery, a data table, a map, etc. So, you can use `main` for a narrative, but not `article` for a gallery. :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(Note that your two examples create a different document outline.)

Use both. The elements serve different purposes and work fine together.

```html
<main>
  <article>
  </article>
</main>
```

If you can only use one element for some reason, go with `main`, because the use of the heading creates an implicit section (where `article` would make this section explicit), and all `article`-related features (like [`address`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sections.html#the-address-element) and [`bookmark`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/links.html#link-type-bookmark)) also work if the `body` is the nearest section. Note that there is no `time`-related feature for `article` anymore (early HTML5 drafts had the `pubdate` attribute, which offered such a feature, but it got removed).

Comment: Using the `main` element is enough:
"When the main content of the page (i.e. excluding footers, headers, navigation blocks, and sidebars) is all one single self-contained composition, that content may be marked with an `article`, but it is technically redundant in that case (since it's self-evident that the page is a single composition, as it is a single document)." Source: [HTML Standard: The article element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-article-element)

Answer (score 0):

article - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_article.asp

> The article tag specifies independent, self-contained content.
>
> An article should make sense on its own and it should be possible to
>   distribute it independently from the rest of the site.
>
> Potential sources for the article element:
>
> *Forum post, Blog post, News, story and Comment*

main - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp

> The main tag specifies the main content of a document.
>
> The content inside the main element should be unique to the
>   document. It should not contain any content that is repeated across
>   documents such as sidebars, navigation links, copyright information,
>   site logos, and search forms.
>
> **Note:** There must not be more than one main element in a document.
>   The main element must NOT be a descendant of an article, aside,
>   footer, header, or nav element.

***In case you repeat it like a blog post I would personally use the article tag***

Answer (score 0):

> The main content section consists of content that is directly related to or expands upon the central topic of a document or central functionality of an application.

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-main-element-20121217

This basically is: 
Main tag is what you looking for, because it wraps all the content on your page. The article tag goes inside this one indeed. (You can look the example in that source link).

But do not take this as a general rule. The article tag might work fine too, as explained here

source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/article

It all depends of your html structure